# explanation on HTTPS Records Query

Tags: rest, https, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

Can anyone please explain how first set, previous set, next set, and the last set of records can be used to query HTTP rest message data. what exactly does this do?
I got some information in ServiceNow website, where i am not able to understand.

[image: https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/rest_api_doc?v=london&id=r_TableAPI-GET]

Can we use this instead of sysparm_limit/sysparm_offset technique to fetch the records?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's there for pagination on your side.

To get the first 10 records you can set sysparm_limit=10 and sysparm_offset=0. To get the next 10 records you should set sysparm_limit=10 and sysparm_offset=10.

Comment: Thanks. But i would like to know how i can make use of this rel="next", rel='Prev", rel="first',rel="last'. what exactly does this do? looking for some examples to understand.